# A question on a sum of $q$-binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, q-analogs, q-series

I am trying to enumerate a certain quantity and at some point I get the following sum:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{m}{m \brack i}_q
\sum_{j=0}^{n-m}
q^{j(m-i)}{n-m \brack j}_q
\sum_{k=0}^{r}
{r\brack k}_q
q^{(j+i)\left(r-k\right)}.
\end{equation}

I wonder if this can be simplified somehow by using a $q$-binomial identity, however, I don't have any working knowledge in that area.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what is your definition of ${n \brack k}_q$?  It can change from place to place.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient

Answer (score 1):

**Partial Answer** If  you let $q = 1$, do the sum over $k$ and then the sum over $j$:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{m} \binom{m}{i}
\sum_{j=0}^{n-m}
 \binom{n-m}{j}
\sum_{k=0}^{r}
 \binom{r}{k} = 2^r \sum_{i=0}^{m} \binom{m}{i}
\sum_{j=0}^{n-m}
 \binom{n-m}{j}
= 2^r \sum_{i=0}^{m} \binom{m}{i}
2^{n-m}
$$

Pull the $2^n$ outside of the summation, and the last sum is the total probability of the binomial distribution.

$$ 2^r \sum_{i=0}^{m} \binom{m}{i}
2^{n-m} = 2^{n+r} \sum_{i=0}^{m} \binom{m}{i}
2^{-m} = 2^{n+r}$$

So we learned this is a type of "iterated summation" and the limiting value is $2^{n+r}$.

---

In your case you need moments of the $q$-binomial distribution.  [Binomial theorem](http://petemcneely.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/q-binomial-theoremcoefficient.pdf) says:

$$ 
\sum_{k=0}^{r}
{r\brack k}_q
x^k q^{\binom{k}{2}} = \prod_{j=0}^r (1+xq^i)
$$

In your case, there's no $q^{\binom{k}{2}}$ factor, the above formula does not apply.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But it doesn't necessarily mean that a simplification is not possible.

Comment: By the way, I found out a little while ago that there exist algorithms that can check this, for instance the $q$-Zeilberger algorithm. But I don't have Maple.